# How the maker ensured the transaction was placed at a certain point within the same block?

Tags: blocks, price

I was observing the MARSH allocation recently and found a bot behavior of extreme luck. One single transaction outperformed many others and the maker paid 101 ETH to the miner for a single transaction.

I am interested in mechanics how this transaction was even possible, especially it's placement in the queue within the very same block.

1. [Initial MARSH transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6a86089e646899f2e41cd7f21353be5a0982f80faae88836789f0ecff3358ebc)
2. [Actor transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xed3f658f0b812a17c1af4e39033c4b684ff64987dc26abcfed006080eac4c68d) (point of interest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Transaction sender paid the miner to do it that way.

Whenever you see transactions which either:

1. Are suspiciously well-placed or
2. Have zero or near-zero *gas price*

(or both), it's probably a product of `Miner Extractable Value (MEV)`. That basically means that someone offers payment to miners (or to a mining pool) to include his transaction in a block in a specific way - and this payment is not in the form of gas price, but something else (for example direct Eth payment to the miner).

MEV is something which is starting to gain popularity fast. There are loads of articles around about it, here's the first google hit: https://blog.chain.link/what-is-miner-extractable-value-mev/

I believe one of the first public implementations is flashbots; you can read more about that here: https://medium.com/flashbots/frontrunning-the-mev-crisis-40629a613752

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt and informative reply! It correlates with the theory I already had... Am I right that such a combo could only be achieved when both transactions where produced by the same (or closely related) actor? I.e. in this particular case, MARSH itself was involved.

Comment: I have no idea what MARSH is, but it probably doesn't matter much. But I don't think it requires any sort of colluding - it's even possible that the "malicious" actor sent his tx to the flashbot miners a week before the release and told them to include it when they see that such and such project is being released - detectable with some sort of code.